# conditional probability of expected value for exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution

Let's assume that X is a random variable which follows exponential distribution. The expected value of this distribution is E . How can I compute the following probability:

$P(X\leq E)$

Thank you so much

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: $E$ is a constant so can only be looked at as degenerated random variable in this context. You write $P(E\mid X\leq E)$ but I cannot recognize a conditional probability in that. This because in $E$ I do not recognize an event.

Comment: Did you possibly mean $P(X\,|\,X≤E)$?

Comment: @lulu And even if so. What is the meaning of $P(X\mid X\leq E)$? Is it some way to denote the conditional distribution of $X$ (under $X\leq E$)? I am not familiar with that notation  and it makes a confusing impression on me.

Comment: @Vera  Yes, at least that's how I would read that, as $P(X=x\,|\,X≤E)$.  Or the OP might intend to ask for the expected value of $X$ given that $X≤E$.  It sure isn't clear what is intended here.

Comment: @lulu you are right , i am asking the expected value of X given that X≤E , thank you

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect that.  For the question:  the probability that $X=x$ conditioned on $X≤E$  is $0$ if $x>E$ and otherwise $\frac {P(X=x)}{P(X≤E)}$.  So, first you will have to compute $P(X≤E)$.

Comment: I edited it , thank you. The $P(X\leq E) $does not correspond the standard deviation which is $1/\lambda$ since E is the expected value of exponential distribution , I am confused at that part

Comment: Not following,  If a random variable $Z$ has a density function $P_Z(z)$ then the probability that $Z≤A$ is $\int_{-\infty}^A P_Z(z)\,dz$.

Comment: Yes, I had thought the same thing , let me explain how I did: X is a random variable wich follows expo. dist. so the density function is  $e^{-\lambda.x}$ . So my integration will be  $\int_{0}^{E} e^{-\lambda.x} dx$ . When I compute this integration , I get $(1/\lambda)-(1/e)$ . I do not know if I am correct

Comment: The density for the exponential distribution is $\lambda\,e^{-\lambda x}$.  Your integral is close but not correct.

Comment: Ah , yes , then  the result will be $1-(1/e)$, which I am not sure

Comment: Yes, that's the answer.

Comment: Then can we interpret this expression like that: Independent from what is the expected value of distribution (which will change according to $\lambda$ the probability of having a random value less than the expected value is always the same which is 1-(1/e) ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The probability distribution function $P(X\le x)=1-e^{-kx}$.  The density function $f(x)=ke^{-kx}$  The mean $E(X)=\int_0^{\infty}kxe^{-kx}dx=\frac{1}{k}$.  You have $E=\frac{1}{k}$.  Therefore $P(X\le E)=1-e^{-1}$.

The title mentions conditional probability.  Where is it?